# Why I can't sync contacts with Twitter/Facebook accounts in Jelly Bean 4.1.1?

Tags: contacts, sync, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean

With my Samsung Galaxy Nexus I can't sync my contacts (from Google Contacts) with those from Twitter/Facebook.

My accounts are up and running, but when i tap "Sync Now" nothing happens. It says "Last sync on ..." but contacts are not updated.

Am I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Because Google disabled it for marketing reasons (pushing Google+ maybe?)
Technically it's just not in the whitelist in an xml file to allow synchronization

According to [niranjanthilak](http://niranjanthilak.com/facebook-sync-for-android-ics-devices/) here is his detailed explanation:

- Facebook application can sync its contacts with the Contacts ( Through ContactsProvider ) only when its whitelisted ( or, in other words , given an escalated permission set ) in the ROM.
- For this , You have to edit the ContactsProvider.apk  and add the whitelisted permission.
- For editing the ContactsProvider.apk ( Which resides in the /system/app/ directory) ,You will need smali ( An assembler/disassembler for Android’s dex format ).
- After disassembling the ContactsProvider.apk using smali , Go to the res/values/ folder ( in the disassembled source ) , and add the file ( arrays.xml ) containing the following content:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <string-array name="unrestricted_packages">
>         <item>com.facebook.katana</item>
>     </string-array>
> </resources>
> ```

- The  com.facebook.katana is the application of facebook. So after adding the arrays.xml file to the /res/values/ folder, Assemble the ContactsProvider using the smali into an unsigned apk file.
- Now , Since ICS , Android 4.0 , Google has disabled this provision of whitelisting applications natively , hence they have obfuscated certain fields from the database.
- Add the column named

> ```
> is_restricted
> ```

to the raw_contacts table inside contacts2.db ( stored in /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/database/ )
- If you have sqlite enabled ( along with busybox ) in your kernel you can use this command for altering the database and adding the necessary field by running it under ADB Shell:

> ```
> sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db
>  'ALTER TABLE raw_contacts ADD COLUMN is_restricted VARCHAR';
> ```

- After adding the column, all the facebook accounts added will be provided with Sync Prompt and they will appear under contacts.

Comment: Thanks. The only problem ATM is that I'm not root, so this will not work :(